# how to correctly Convert time on table sum

Tags: excel, excel-2010

When using convert to derive seconds from a table having times, the formula stumbles when it encounters the totals-cell. Is there a remedy? If so, what? Guidance requested.

here is that table
[the times are in m:ss format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbKU8.png)
the formula used is =CONVERT(tableName[@actual],"day","sec")

Answer (score 0):

If you must use structured references, please try (for the total):

```
=CONVERT(TableName[[#Totals],[actual]],"day","sec")
```

Other than other options such as R1C1 etc., it might be easier simply to sum the correct values you see.

Comment: This was our workaround; thanks @pnuts for the validation.

Answer (score -1):

Please read up in how Excel treats dates and times somewhere. In essence, a date is a long integer counting days since Jan 1, 1900. Today = (yesterday + 1). Since 1 represents one day, it also represents 24 hours. Therefore 1/24 equals 1 hour, 2/24 = 2 hours, 12/24 = half a day = 12 hours = 0.5 days. 43522.0 was 0:00 this morning. 43522.5 will be 12 noon today.

One minute = 1 / 24 / 60.
One second = 1 / 24 / 60 / 60
The CONVERT function simply does this calculation.

The problem is in your data, however. If you enter 1:14 this may be 1 minute and 14 seconds or 1 hour and 14 minutes, depending upon your cell format. The underlying number would be different. Or there may not be any underlying number at all. Your cell may simply contain a text string, like "1:14", and that would be impossible to do calculations with, including SUM or CONVERT.

To find out what your cell contains, set a cell format of *General* for it. If the cell contains a number you will then see it. If it doesn't change, it's text.